# get data to draw a gauss curve

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, curves

I would like to know how to get some data from a normal distribution to draw its gauss curve.
I have the standard deviation, the average and the x, but I don't know how to get some points to draw the curve, can you tell me please?

Thanks

Comment: With a calculator or computer you can just plug into the density function. Otherwise you are perhaps best off plugging in $x_n=\mu+\sqrt{2 \sigma n}$ where $n$ is like $-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3$. You will find that the density is exponential in $n$; specifically it is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi} \sigma} e^{-n}$. (However, note that $x_n$ are not evenly spaced). So you can get a sketch that way.

Comment: Ok thanks, so how can I use the density function to draw the curve?

Comment: I don't use excel but need to draw a gauss curve in an android app. I'm looking for the data points with my average and my standard deviation

Comment: The curve is the graph of the density function, so I don't understand your question.

Comment: The answer below helped me, problem solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means plotting
$$
N(x;\mu,\sigma) = 
\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}} 
e^{-(1/2)\left((x-\mu)/\sigma\right)^2}
$$

You can try it [here](http://ggbtu.be/m3185277).

[image: example]

Comment: Thanks. So if I have x=3 (for example), I can use your function to calculate  one point, but I don't understand how to get other points to draw the curve. Sorry for my lack of knowledge about that

Comment: Ok thank you very much for help

Comment: It is a function in one unknown $x$ and having two parameters $\mu$ (mean) and $\sigma$ (standard deviation). To plot it you keep your $\mu$ and $\sigma$ values fixed and vary your $x$ argument values, picking a set of values $x_i$, $\{ x_1, x_2, \dotsc \}$, to calculate the values $N(x)$, getting a set of function values $N_i = N(x_i)$, $\{ N_1, N_2, \dotsc\}$. Then you can plot the pairs $(x_i, N_i)$. In the above example this work is done by the plotting software to come up with the red graph.

Answer (score 1):

Since the density function is $N(x;μ,σ)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sigma^2 2π}}e^{−\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$

The value of the above formula is the height of the graph for a point $x$. If you try lots of different values of $x$ you will get lots of points for the height of the graph at different values of $x$.

Comment: Ok thank you I can't put you +1 because don't have enough reputation but thanks